# No sirve Scroll en WebView de Android

Tags: android, webview-android

Estoy cargando una pagina web en un **WebView**, pero no me deja hacer el `scroll`.

Esta es la imagen desde el navegador **Google Chrome** en una pc, aquí si sirve bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en `Android` cargándolo desde un **WebView** no me sirve el `scroll`, no se desplaza hacia abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Solo tienes el problema con los google maps desde un webview?

Comment: sii, pero no es google maps, es un mapa de Arcgis.

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Debería funcionarte sino lo que puedes probar es hacer un ScrollView y meter dentro el WebView así fuerzas que haya scroll

Lo haría así

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">

//Añadir el webView dentro


</ScrollView
```

Comment: Pero es que el WebView carga toda la pagina, con lo que copiaste el scroll seria para el WebView y eso no necesito, si ves las imagenes es una informacion que sale al dar clic que no sirve en android

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de poner un WebView dentro de un ScrollView, WebView tiene la opción de agregar un scrollbar. Este es un código de ejemplo:

```
WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
v.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
v.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Sin embargo, los viejos navegadores de android no permiten los eventos multitouch del javascript runtime. Aún así, si la API muestra los controles de zoom, podría ser una opción. Creo que no se puede hacer mucho al respecto, salvo incluir el mapa vía API